# Losing functionality of some Jquery methods after using $(selector).load("myMethod")

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, partial-views

Here is my scenario...

i'm using partial views to load a page. To load to partial view on the page I use the JQuery method

```
$("#elementA").load("myMethod")
```

myMethod does an ajax call which returns my partial view with a list of objects. All this works fine. The problem is that inside one of my partial views i have a click event that should fire

```
$("#elementB").modal()
```

After i call

```
$("#elementA").load("myMethod")
```

the

```
$("#elementB").modal()
```

method does not respond...

The same

```
$("#elementB").modal()
```

works if i don't use the load() function but then i dont know how to refresh the list after a new element is added to my database without using the `$("#elementA").load("myMethod")`....

I would apreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Comment: it would be better if you post JS/HTML code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have your click events bound using something like `on()` (or `live` in older versions of jQuery, though `on` is now preferred).

This would ensure that any elements added to the page after the initial binding is made will also be subject to the same event handler.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#elementA").load("myMethod")` will replace all content inside of it and if `$("#elementB")` is a child of `#elementA`, than of course it will be removed. But how you call a `$("#elementB").modal()`? if it is in `onclick` handler of `$("#elementA")` child - than you must use jQuery **on/live** method to bind your handler instead of **bind/click**.